# Extracting numbers and text from string field using Python Parser of ArcMap Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

[image]

This is a similar question to [Extracting numbers from string field using Python Parser of ArcMap Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133659/extracting-numbers-from-string-field-using-python-parser-of-arcmap-field-calcula/372626#372626)

I have a similar issue in ArcMap 10.6. I have a field named 'SIZE' that holds number values and size unit (e.g. '200 mm' or '12"').

I am trying first to extract the numbers and deal with the units after.
I created a new string field named 'SIZE2', while using the same code, but when I run it the values in 'SIZE2' stay NULL.

```
def makestr(SIZE):
 numlist = []
 for s in SIZE:
     if s.isdigit():
         numlist.append(s)
 return ''.join(numlist)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct, currently you are pointing to the wrong field when using `makestr(!SIZE2!)` under `SIZE2 =` which is incorrect. You should point to the `!SIZE!` field instead of `!SIZE2!` field.

The correct expression is `makestr(!SIZE!)` when you executing the function under `SIZE2 =`.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [UpdateCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) approach which iterates through each row in the attributes, extracts the numeric values in the field `SIZE` and writes them to the field `SIZE2`.

```
import arcpy

fc = '/path/to/your.gdb/featureclass'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("SIZE", "SIZE2")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = ''.join([x for x in row[0] if x.isdigit()])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```